# Custom fonts not loading on mobile version of website

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, mobile, font-face

I have added a custom font to my website. It is working perfectly fine on desktop on all browsers, but is not working when testing on mobile.

I have been through all the questions on SO regarding this issue and have not found a resolution in them.

Here is my CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    src: local('Proxima Nova'),
         url('/fonts/Proxima Nova Alt Regular-webfont.svg') format('svg'), 
         url('/fonts/Proxima Nova Alt Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/Proxima Nova Alt Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/ProximaNovaA-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/fonts/Proxima Nova Alt Regular-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
}

body {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
}
```

As I said, works perfectly fine on all desktop browsers, but not loading at all on mobile. According to ngrok, the fonts are loading with a response code of `206 Partial Content`. No idea why

Any help?